# Corda Private Network connectivity

Tags: corda

We are having one private corda network setup and our Cordapp is deployed in the network and its working fine, so now we have a requirement to integrate with another private network. Basically we need to communicate node A from private network 1 to a node B in another private network 2. Can someone guide me through some documentation link.